# backbone javascript Cant remove item from localstorage but can save

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, model, local-storage

I could not understand my I could not remove items from a collection, so tried just using a model. However my problem still persists, I can save but not remove. I can remove from  the collection, so I'm thinking its an issue with local storage, maybe I'm using it wrong.

This is my model. The add function updates localstorage but remove does not clear it.

```
 bb.model.Setting = Backbone.Model.extend(_.extend({   
  localStorage:  new Store("rrr"),
  defaults: {
  theme: 'e'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    var self = this
   },
  removed: function()
  {
      var self = this
      _.bindAll(self)
     this.destroy()
      this.clear()

   },
  add: function(value)
  {
      var self = this
      _.bindAll(self)
   this.set({theme:"dggfd"});
     this.save();

  },
   }))
```

Comment: I dont think there is enough information for us to debug. Can you add your `Store` code and other information or maybe a JSfiddle?

Comment: I needed to do this to remove from localstorage, was only removing from screeen,   this.fetch();
       var modelToDelete = this.at(0) //take first model
          modelToDelete.destroy();
          this.create({theme:value});